# How to identify the architecture of a microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, embedded

I am currently learning about microcontroller internal architecture. I came across terms such as Harvard and Von Newman architecture. I read about the difference between these two. But, is there a way to identify the architecture just by looking at the Memory map.

Comment: This question isn't really answerable, because in practice many modern MCUs are a hybrid of both - a Von Newman *programming model* but data paths that operate most efficiently when used in a Harvard fashion, even though the cross possibilities (data access to flash, code access to RAM) are often supported at a lower efficiency due to the need for automatic bus arbitration.  This is also a topic that's been covered here a fair amount in the past.

Comment: If you see a single memory address space it's probably von Neumann (code and data in a shared address space.) If you see more than one address space, it's probably Harvard. If you see a unified cache system, von Neumann. If several cache systems, probably Harvard. But probably no single bright line, either.

Comment: @jonk distinct caches are extremely common in Von Neuman-ish machines, potentially including the computer you are typing at.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I worked on chipsets at Intel and know the internals pretty well. So you don't need to nitpick with me. I was just providing a simplistic answer consistent with the OP's question. I was not interested in providing an *actual* answer, though. So just a comment.

Comment: I dont understand the obsession with Von Newman vs Harvard, they are interesting perhaps in a text book just like using MIPS to talk/walk through teaching pipelines, but the reality is they dont matter beyond that.  As Chris pointed out the world is full of hybrids, a pure Harvard is somewhat useless in real world applications, the extra busses dont make a lot of sense.  Far easier to mark each transaction, and thus make it easy to separate i and d caches independent of what architecture you pretend or advertise to be...but really arent in a textbook sense.

Comment: If you want to learn about internal architectures, first off what do you mean by that, harvard vs von newman are not really interesting topics, examine the instruction set ponder the many ways it could have been and possibly was implemented, much of it is not mcu related but just processor in general, then if you are interested in mcu related its just adding a system on a chip basically. and perhaps focusing a lot on power which is not so much architecture but implementation (clock gating sure)

Comment: A non-sequiteur:  There are some oddball architectures out there... such as the (not yet released) Propeller 2 microcontroller, which has some mind-bending features that may make it difficult to categorise into the two types you've mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Well simply look at the definition of the two terms.  If the databook says that the program space (flash/rom)(0x0000 to 0x8000 for example) is in a particular address space for example and it also has the ram and/or peripherals in that same space (0x0000 to 0x4000 for example), then there you go.  If it does not have address conflicts between instruction address space and data access space in the documentation then no you cannot tell strictly from the address space.

Now saying that that still doesnt give you the answer as pointed out in the comments these are hybrids, modern cpu busses (and that is a loaded term as to when this started) share the address and data busses, but have additional controls that include transaction type which include is this an instruction fetch or a data cycle as well as features like is this cacheable or not.  Go look at the arm AXI/AHB bus documentation.  As ARM does you can claim you are both Von Newman and Harvard (well they claim harvard if I remember right for the mcu cores) because they both "share the same bus" and "isolate the instruction and data accesses".  Which touch on the two definitions.  I think ARM has gone even further by having multiple busses on the core, but at least one if not all can do both I and D transactions in the same address space to the same targets.

Von Newman vs Harvard is about the least interesting topic when it comes to processor/mcu architecture design.  Focus on the instruction set and implementation, and for an mcu the additional interesting aspects my have to do with managing power consumption and size/cost.

Comment: also understand there are various address decoding layers, before you get to the edge of an ARM core for example or the pins on a processor chip some addresses have been decoded and transactions consumed, not just L1 caching but other items.  so the picture of a processor and one or more busses doesnt make sense with respect to reality...

Answer (score 2):

> But, is there a way to identify the architecture just by looking at the Memory map.

Yes. It is very easy to see.

#### Harvard:

[image: atmega32 memory map]

#### Von Neumann:

[image: stm32f0 memory map]

Do you see it?
The Harvard has **three** memory maps starting at 0x0, while the Neumann has **one** space starting at 0x0.

The Harvard will have different instructions to access each memory space. This is a disadvantage when working with pointers. Because address 0x100 can be in more than one place. Whilst at an von Neumann 0x100 is unique.

In its simplest form Harvard is faster, because it can run multiple memory access at once. Eg: a Cortex M0 and an Atmel AVR.

But in reality, chip designers have taken the best of both worlds.
Look at an ARM Cortex M4 and it's access to the bus. The core has 3 bus interfaces, one to access *instructions* (I), one to access *data* (D), one to access *peripherals* (S). All three can be used simultaneously. The underlying chip architecture defines which busses will be used for which memory for optimal speed.
[image: stm32f4 core bus access]
Logically, it's a von Neumann, physically it's a Harvard.

Answer (score -1):

The timing diagrams provide lotta info about those architectures. Harvard has concurrency of data and program.

With all the transistors, and the tiny line widths, its easy to implement concurrency, indeed likely preferable because the two memories need not be muxed together.

Comment: Timing diagrams describe external interfaces, not internal memory access patterns. Since most microcontrollers don't have external program memory, there would be no program memory access listed. (And even if there were, that wouldn't prove anything.)